# Dev dependencies needed for Heroku webpack build

Tags: heroku, webpack

I was under the impression that I wouldn't need the devDependencies to be included when I deploy to Heroku a react based app, using Webpack. For example, here's my package.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "",
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server",
    "build": "rimraf dist && export NODE_ENV=production && webpack --config ./webpack.production.config.js --progress --profile --colors",
    "postinstall": "node deploy",
    "eslint": "eslint .",
    "jscs": "jscs ."
  },
```

and deploy.js:

```
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    var child_process = require('child_process');
    child_process.exec("webpack -p --config webpack.production.config.js", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
      console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
      if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
      }
    });
  }
```

and the Procfile

```
web ./node_modules/.bin/babel-node server.js
```

However, when I push to Heroku, I'm constantly getting a webpack command not recognized, so I included all of the devDependencies as normal dependencies to have it working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please attach your package.json

Answer (score 10):

Heroku set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to true by default to install dependencies only. If you would like to install devDependencies, you can disable production mode:

`$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

However, since you usually don’t want all devDependencies in your production builds, it’s preferable to move only the dependencies you actually need for production builds into dependencies (bower, grunt, gulp, etc).